# TSQL returning the first record

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a SQL Server 2008 table with the following data (Small sample)

```
id                                          Date    Value
20448D6F-4099-408D-85FE-11EC6690CDB8    2010-06-01  1
20448D6F-4099-408D-85FE-11EC6690CDB8    2010-06-02  2
20448D6F-4099-408D-85FE-11EC6690CDB8    2010-06-03  3
20448D6F-4099-408D-85FE-11EC6690CDB8    2010-06-04  4
20448D6F-4099-408D-85FE-11EC6690CDB8    2010-06-05  NULL
EF595DE6-FF57-4625-8254-287F49843445    2010-06-02  2
EF595DE6-FF57-4625-8254-287F49843445    2010-06-03  3
EF595DE6-FF57-4625-8254-287F49843445    2010-06-04  4
EF595DE6-FF57-4625-8254-287F49843445    2010-06-05  NULL
C6F459EF-1493-4864-81C2-E5B55283EF0C    2010-06-04  45
C6F459EF-1493-4864-81C2-E5B55283EF0C    2010-06-05  NULL
```

I am running the query

```
select * 
from [test].[dbo].[testtable]
where id in 
         (
            select id 
            from [test].[dbo].[testtable] 
             where Date='2010-06-05' and Value is null
          )
  and Date = DATEADD(D, -4, '2010-06-05')
```

which returns

```
id                                          Date            Value
20448D6F-4099-408D-85FE-11EC6690CDB8    2010-06-01          1
```

but when a record does not exist for `2010-06-01` I would like to return the next min date

So the results I would see from the sample would be

```
id                                          Date            Value
20448D6F-4099-408D-85FE-11EC6690CDB8    2010-06-01          1
EF595DE6-FF57-4625-8254-287F49843445    2010-06-02          2
C6F459EF-1493-4864-81C2-E5B55283EF0C    2010-06-04          45
```

I have millions of records how can I do this in a T-SQL query?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `MIN` aggregate in a subquery:

```
SELECT t.Id, t.Date, t.Value
FROM [test].[dbo].[testtable] t
    JOIN (
        SELECT Min(Date) MinDate, Id
        FROM [test].[dbo].[testtable] 
        WHERE Date >= '6/1/2010'
        GROUP BY Id
    ) t2 ON t.Id = t2.Id AND t.Date = t2.MinDate
WHERE t.Id IN (
    SELECT id 
    FROM [test].[dbo].[testtable] 
    WHERE Date='2010-06-05' and Value is null
    )
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8644f/1)

Comment: that will not work ther can also be record like EF595DE6-FF57-4625-8254-287F49843445
2010-05-05
444 which will be returned

Comment: @user2062675 -- just add where criteria so that the date must be greater than or equal to 6/1/2010 then

Comment: Sorry i am a newb at this can you modify your answer?

Comment: @user2062675 -- I've edited the post -- see if that doesn't work for you!

Comment: @user2062675 -- np, glad I could help!